# Comparing two lists and getting differences

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have two lists. They contain objects of different types, but both types contain id and name, and id is what I am comparing on. 
List one is fetched from DB, and list two is sent from frontend.

What I need to do is loop through them and find which list item is newly added and which one was deleted.

I was able to do it, but the problem is that it look ugly.

Let's say I have a object that is called NameDTO which can have id and name. List two is filled with that type of objects.

This is how I did it:

```
final ArrayList<NamedDTO> added = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<NamedDTO> removed = new ArrayList<>();

for(NamedDTO listTwoObject : listTwo) {
   boolean contained = false;
   for(SomeObject listOneObject : listOne) {
       if(listTwoObject.getId().equals(listOneObject.getId()) {
           contained = true;
       }
   }
   if(!contained) {
      added.add(listTwoObject);
   }
}

for(SomeObject listOneObject : listOne) {
   boolean contained = false;
   for(NamedDTO listTwoObject : listTwo) {
       if(listTwoObject.getId().equals(listOneObject.getId()) {
           contained = true;
       }
   }
   if(!contained) {
      removed.add(new NamedDTO(listOneObject.getId(), listOneObject.getName()));
  }
}
```

This works, I have tested it. 
Are there better solutions?
I was thinking of using Sets so I can compare them, Is there a downside to that ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: *But the problem is it look ugly*. What do you mean by that. Is it too much code or is it the performance that you are talking about? What's your key objective here?

Comment: Why you not create another List with only ID of 2nd list and check if it contains that ID or not ?

Comment: It to much code. I am trying something different, I will post it later.

I need the name also.

Comment: You are comparing an object with itself all the time. Before you start thinking about ugliness, you should think about the correctness.

Comment: Use a hashed based connection such as Set or Map to avoid O(N^2)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is the example scenario:

- listOne [datab] items: `[A, B, C, D]`
- listTwo [front] items: `[B, C, D, E, F]`

and what you need to get as an effect is:

- added: `[E, F]`
- deleted: `[A]`

---

First thing first, I would use some type adapter or extend the different types from one common class and `override` the `equals` method so you can match them by `id` and `name`

Secondly, this is very easy operations on sets (you could use set's but list are fine too). I recommend using a library: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html

And now basically:

- added is `listTwo - listOne`
- deleted is `listOne - listTwo`

and using java code:

- added: `CollectionUtils.removeAll(listTwo, listOne)`
- deleted: `CollectionUtils.removeAll(listOne, listTwo)`

---

Otherwise, all collections implementing `Collection` ([Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-)) also has `removeAll` method, which you can use.

Comment: This answer would make sense if the OP was okay with using a third party library. We can't be sure unless we ask.

Comment: @CKing ok we can do without as well.

Comment: I have looked into this, and found it very simple and easy to read, which in my case is important since i am not the only developer working on this project. I will use this.

Answer (score 18):

I propose solution using java 8 streams:

```
    ArrayList<ObjOne> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new ObjOne("1","1"),new ObjOne("3","3"),new ObjOne("2","2")));
    ArrayList<ObjTwo> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new ObjTwo("1","1"),new ObjTwo("3","3"),new ObjTwo("4","4")));

    List<ObjOne> removed = list.stream().filter(o1 -> list2.stream().noneMatch(o2 -> o2.getId().equals(o1.getId())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.print("added ");
    removed.forEach(System.out::println);

    List<ObjTwo> added = list2.stream().filter(o1 -> list.stream().noneMatch(o2 -> o2.getId().equals(o1.getId())))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.print("removed ");
    added.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is basically your solution but implemented using streams, which will make your code shorter and easer to read

Comment: This is basically just a different way of writing the OP's approach - it has the same complexity (`list.size() * list2.size()`). Still, +1 for a slightly more compact version

Comment: Thanks, as you can see i commented below code, that this is his solution, but it's shorter and easier to read :)

Comment: Important to know, API level 24 or higher is required to use Stream. So not usable for everyone.

Answer (score 10):

This nested list processing is not only ugly, it’s inefficient. You are always better off storing the IDs of one list into a `Set` allowing efficient lookup, then process the other list utilizing the `Set`. This way, you’re not performing `list1.size()` times `list2.size()` operations, but `list1.size()` plus `list2.size()` operations, which is a significant difference for larger lists. Then, since both operations are fundamentally the same, it’s worth abstracting them into a method:

```
public static <A,B,R,ID> List<R> extract(
    List<A> l1, List<B> l2, Function<A,ID> aID, Function<B,ID> bID, Function<A,R> r) {

    Set<ID> b=l2.stream().map(bID).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return l1.stream().filter(a -> !b.contains(aID.apply(a)))
             .map(r).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This method can be used as

```
List<NamedDTO> added   = extract(listTwo, listOne, NamedDTO::getId, SomeObject::getId,
                                 Function.identity());
List<NamedDTO> removed = extract(listOne, listTwo, SomeObject::getId, NamedDTO::getId,
                                 so -> new NamedDTO(so.getId(), so.getName()));
```

Since swapping the two lists requires the helper method to be independent from the element types, it expects functions for accessing the id property, which can be specified via method references. Then, a function describing the result element is required, which is an identity function in one case (just getting the `NamedDTO`) and a lambda expression constructing a `NamedDTO` from `SomeObject` in the other.

The operation itself is as straight-forward as described above, iterate over one list, map to the id and collect into a `Set`, then, iterate over the other list, keep only elements whose id is not in the set, map to the result type and collect into a `List`.

Answer (score 4):

If these id's are unique, you could put them in a HashSet and find thus the ids you are interested in:

```
    Set<Integer> uiList = Stream.of(new FromUI(1, "db-one"), new FromUI(2, "db-two"), new FromUI(3, "db-three"))
            .map(FromUI::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    Set<Integer> dbList = Stream.of(new FromDB(3, "ui-one"), new FromDB(5, "ui-five"))
            .map(FromDB::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    uiList.removeIf(dbList::remove);

added/uiSet :   [1,2]
removed/dbSet : [5]
```

I've created `FromUI` and `FromDB` classes with a constructor that takes the id and name as input.

I also assume that if an element is contained in the `uiSet`, but not in `dbSet` is has been added and the other way around.

Comment: Now, you’ve simplified  to much. While `Collectors.toSet()` currently returns a `HashSet`, it’s not guaranteed to return a mutable `Set`, hence, you have to use `toCollection(HashSet::new)`. By the way, the `oneSet.removeIf(otherSet::remove)` trick is neat, I’m sure, I might find a use for it sometimes. This will work even with `map1.keySet().removeIf(map2.keySet()::remove)`, which allows to have the owners in the `values()`…

Comment: @Holger oh damn that is scary! I've read the doc (I should have by now) and I had not known about *mutability*. Big thx for this.